# Why might similar .NET Core services behave differently?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two .net core 2.2 services, InitialisationHandler and WorkingTicketHandler, one holds initial information and the other is intended to hold a working ticket.
The InitialisationHandler always has its information ready when asked, but the WorkingTicketHandler always returns a null record.

I need to figure out how to have WorkingTicketHandler hold on to its data just like InitialisationHandler does.

Both are added to as transient in ConfigureServices, and created as identically as possible.

There is one key difference, the InitialisationHandler has its data created during startup by its constructor method and is only ever read from thereafter, whereas the WorkingTicketHandler is written to by a controller and re read in the same controller (Get vs Post).

```
using VTModels.Other;

namespace VT_Online22.Infrastructure.Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interface for the WorkingTicket Service
    /// </summary>
    public interface IWorkingTicketHandler
    {
        WorkingTicket GetWorkingTicket();
        void SaveWorkingTicket(WorkingTicket  argWorkingTicket);
        void ClearWorkingTicket();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// WorkingTicket service class definition
    /// </summary>
    public class WorkingTicketHandler : IWorkingTicketHandler
    {

        public WorkingTicketHandler()
        {
            this.WorkingTicket = new WorkingTicket();
        }

        public WorkingTicket GetWorkingTicket()
        {
            return this.WorkingTicket;
        }

        public void SaveWorkingTicket(WorkingTicket arg_WorkingTicket)
        {
            this.WorkingTicket = arg_WorkingTicket;
        }

        public void ClearWorkingTicket()
        {
            this.WorkingTicket = new WorkingTicket();
        }

        private WorkingTicket WorkingTicket;
        private static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(WorkingTicketHandler));
    }
}
```

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using SharedModels.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VT_OnlineCore.Infrastructure.Other;
using VTModels.Models;

namespace VT_Online22.Infrastructure.Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interface for the Initialization Service
    /// </summary>
    public interface IInitializationHandler
    {
        void Initialize();
        CConfigMasterBase GetConfig();
        IEnumerable<CScopeMasterBase> GetScopes(string clientId);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialization service class definition
    /// </summary>
    public class InitializationHandler : IInitializationHandler
    {

        public InitializationHandler(IConfiguration configTech)
        {
            ConfigurationTech = configTech;
            Initialize();
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            this.ldh = new LocalDataHandler(logger, this.ConfigurationTech);
            this.config = new CConfigMasterBase();
            LoadConfig();
        }

        public IEnumerable<CScopeMasterBase> GetScopes(string clientId)
        {
            IEnumerable<CScopeMasterBase> scopes = new List<CScopeMasterBase>();
            scopes =  this.ldh.GetScopes(clientId);
            return scopes;
        }
        public CConfigMasterBase GetConfig()
        {

            return this.config;
        }

        private async Task LoadConfig()
        {
            this.config =   this.ldh.GetConfig();           
        }

        private LocalDataHandler ldh;
        private CConfigMasterBase config;
        private IEnumerable<CScopeMasterBase> scopes;
        private static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(InitializationHandler));

        public IConfiguration ConfigurationTech { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

```
services.AddTransient<IInitializationHandler,InitializationHandler>();
services.AddTransient<IWorkingTicketHandler, WorkingTicketHandler>();
```

Comment: There's nothing similar between those classes, except that both are Transient so anything they contain will be lost as soon as the current scope ends. In that sense, `WorkingTicketHandler` is little better than a value stored in a controller's field - it only exists for a single request

Comment: I assume by "returns a null record" you mean that `GetWorkingTicket()` method returns null. You should really provide the code in which you retrieve said record. My guess would be that the issue lies there somewhere, since judging from this if you just did a straight forward call after injecting `WorkingTicketHandler` service, it should return the `WorkingTicket` instance that was created in its constructor, but not null.

Comment: Yes, returns null. There is little value in showing the calls to save / get the working ticket. Just invoking the function. It has been pointed out to me in the past hour that since the save is in a httpget method and the GetWorkingTicket is in a HttpPost, these are distinct requests and will have different instances. What is worse is that if all this did actually work then every signed on user would have access to the same working ticket just as they have access to the same config, and while that works well for config, it is not so good for an item being purchased.

Comment: I have been using session state before looking at this as an alternative. This is due to session state being shareable within the same browser session. I will now look at the possibility of persisting the working ticket to the database which opens up the possibility of saving a purchase as draft then resuming it at a later stage. Did I hear anyone call 'Scope Creep'?